# Rails - How to pass Sprockets::Context in manual sass compiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets

I'm using the following code snippet to manually compile a sass manifest with some variable overrides appended.

```
template = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/schemes/#{scheme}/css/styles.css.scss")

scheme_variables.each do |key, value|
  template << "$#{key}:#{value};\n"
end

engine = Sass::Engine.new(template, { 
  :syntax => :scss,
  :cache => false,
  :read_cache => false,
  :style => :compressed,
  :filesystem_importer => Sass::Rails::SassImporter,
  :load_paths => MyApp::Application.assets.paths,
  :sprockets => {
    :context => ?,
    :environment => MyApp::Application.assets
  }
})
output = engine.render
```

The Sass::Engine constructor wants a sprockets context and environment in the options hash.  What do I put in for the context?  The first thing I tried was...

```
:context => MyApp::Application.assets.context_class,
```

...but that gives me the following error "undefined method `font_path' for #" when it hits one of my sass asset helpers.

The second thing I tried was...

```
:context => ActionController::Base.helpers,
```

...That fixed the asset helper issue, but throws the following error "undefined method `depend_on' for #" when it tries to work through my glob imports (e.g. @import "mixins/*").

I'm using Rails 4.2 and sass-rails 5.0.3.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this in a slightly different way - using Sass::Rails::ScssTemplate's render method.  Basically, I write my altered css string out to a file and pass it into the Sass::Rails::ScssTemplate constructor.  I then compile and remove the temp file when it's done.  This doesn't feel great, but it's working well for me.

```
scheme_css_dir = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/schemes/#{scheme}/css"
css = File.read("#{scheme_css_dir}/styles.css.scss")

variables_str = ''
scheme_variables.each do |key, value|
  variables_str << "$#{key}:#{value};\n"
end

css.gsub!('@import "./variables";', variables_str)

file = Tempfile.new(['styles', '.css.scss'], scheme_css_dir)
file.write(css)
file.close

abs_path = file.path
relative_path = abs_path[Rails.root.to_s.size + 1..-1]

template = Sass::Rails::ScssTemplate.new(abs_path)
environment = Evrconnect::Application.assets
context = environment.context_class.new(
  :environment => environment,
  :name => relative_path,
  :filename => abs_path,
  :metadata => {}
)
output = template.render(context)

file.unlink
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing in [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676993/dynamically-render-a-sass-file-through-sprockets)—did you figure out how to do this without creating a tmp file?

Comment: Yes it can be done without a tmp file. Please see my answer. I hope I'm not 3 years too late ;)

Answer (score 4):

With using Sass::Rails::ScssTemplate you can render your sass code with this snippet:

```
template = '...' # Your sass code

logical_path = pathname = ''
environment = Rails.application.assets
context = environment.context_class.new(environment, logical_path, pathname)

template = Sass::Rails::ScssTemplate.new(pathname) { template }
output = template.render(context, {})
```

If you want to render from a file then just add its path to pathname and its asset path to logical_path.

For me it works with Rails 4.2.5.1 and sass-rails 5.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question, you need to supply either the current `view_context`, or create one with `ActionView::Base.new`.

http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/view_context

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5.x, Sprockets v3.7.x

> NOTE: Following method requires: `Rails.application.config.assets.compile == true`, i.e., set `config.assets.compile = true`. Check [Sprockets README](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/README.md)

I manually returned compiled source for sass/js, using the following code.

```
# For Scss Assets
def pdf_stylesheet_link_tag(name)
  if Rails.env.development?
    asset = Rails.application.assets.find_asset(name + '.scss')
    raw ('<style type="text/css">' + asset.source + '</style>')
  else
    raw ('<style type="text/css">' + pdf_asset_contents(name, '.css') + '</style>')
  end
end

# For Javascript Assets
def pdf_javascript_include_tag(name, *type)
  if Rails.env.development?
    if debug? # Can be used to check `debug == true` in params for current route
      javascript_include_tag(name)
    else
      asset = Rails.application.assets.find_asset(name + '.js')
      raw ('<script>' + asset.source + '</script>')
    end
  else
    javascript_tag pdf_asset_contents(name, '.js')
  end
end
```

Above code actually helps to dynamically pass compiled version of sass/js
to [Wicked_PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf), which actually helps to load styles and js on Generated PDFs, for Dev Environments.

`pdf_stylesheet_link_tag` can be used as a helper for templates, in development/stage (where, `config.assets.precompile == false`), instead of using `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag`(which actually requires a path to precompiled source-file).

Answer (score 0):

After overnight trial and errors, I found and want to share todays's way of doing it ("today" meaning: rails 5.2.1 and sprockets 3.7.2).

Work as expected: no need of a temp file, accept @import, allow asset path helpers.

```
# Compile SASS and return the resulting string
# Pass the file path and name without 'sass' extension, relative to assets/stylesheets
def compile_sass(stylesheet) 
  # Load file content
  path = Rails.root.join 'app', 'assets', 'stylesheets', "#{stylesheet}.sass"
  sass = File.read path

  # Configure engine
  environment = Sprockets::Railtie.build_environment Rails.application
  scope = environment.context_class.new environment: environment, \
    filename: "/", metadata: {}
  scope.sass_config.merge! cache: false, style: :compressed

  # Compile
  engine = Sass::Rails::SassTemplate.new {sass}
  engine.render scope
end
```

Other `sass_config` options can be found here : https://github.com/sass/ruby-sass/blob/stable/doc-src/SASS_REFERENCE.md#options

Answer (score 0):

The following works with `rails` 5.2.0, `sprockets` 3.7.2, `sassc-rails` 1.3.0 and `sassc` 1.12.1:

```rb
 template = '...' # Your sass code

 environment = Sprockets::Railtie.build_environment(Rails.application)
 engine = SassC::Rails::SassTemplate.new

 engine.call(environment: environment,
             filename: '/', 
             data: template, 
             metadata: {})[:data]
```