# Dynamically render a sass file through sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets

I want, from a helper, to render some variables in a `.scss.erb` template that makes use of the `image-url()` sass function:

```
// template.scss.erb

#<%= id %> {
  background-image: image-url('<%= image_file %>');
}
```

So far, the ERB part has been easy:
*(leveraging [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9734736/625710))*

```rb
vars_binding = OpenStruct.new(
                 id:         'foo', 
                 image_file: 'foo.jpg'
               ).instance_eval { binding }

template = File.read('path/to/template.scss.erb')

rendered_sass = ERB.new(template).result(vars_binding)
```

Running that code, `sass` is now equal to:

```
#foo {
  background-image: image-url('foo.jpg');
}
```

However, when I next try to run:

```rb
css = Sass::Engine.new(
  rendered_sass,
  syntax:     :scss,
  cache:      false,
  load_paths: view_context.assets.paths,
  read_cache: false,
  style:      :compressed
).render
```

It returns

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from …/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:267:in `sprockets_context'
```

because the call to `Sass::Engine` doesn’t provide a Sprockets context.

If I remove `image-url()` from the `.scss.erb` template, and replace it with the native `url()`, it will then render correctly as CSS, no problem.

**So how do I render this template within a sprockets context?**

Answer (score 8):

After digging through a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376024/rails-how-to-pass-sprocketscontext-in-manual-sass-compiling?lq=1), and a lot of trial and error, I found my solution: I have to supply a `:sprockets` hash when calling `Sass::Engine.new`.

```rb
css = Sass::Engine.new(
  rendered_sass,
  syntax:     :scss,
  cache:      false,
  load_paths: view_context.assets.paths,
  read_cache: false,
  style:      :compressed,

  # The key ingredient…
  sprockets:  {
    context:     view_context,
    environment: view_context.assets
  }
).render
```

It should be noted that `view_context` was passed from a view file, but it could have also been `ActionView::Base.new`

Comment: Thank you! Something else I am struggling with is that I'd like to make the `image-url()` SASS helper generate absolute paths. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you give a bit more information about the view_context?  I get a no method error when trying to call #assets on an instance of ActionView::Base.  I'm certain this is close to what I need, but I don't really understand what the sprockets context is doing here.

Comment: @sammms instead of calling `assets` on `view_context`, you can call it on `Rails.application`

Comment: For recent versions of Rails, you need to set `config.assets.compile = true` in your `application.rb`, or `assets` will be `nil` in production.

More info on it in https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/237

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with the same issue I have found a live example of the same functionality on a Github page, surprisingly not gemified.

https://github.com/BLauris/custom-css-for-user

There is an article of the author explaining the method on this link:
http://www.diatomenterprises.com/dynamically-compile-stylesheets-with-rails-and-sass/